# How to show AlertDialog over WebviewScaffold in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, android-alertdialog, webviewscaffold

I am going to open `AlertDialog` over `WebviewScaffold` but it not shown. When I open the `AlertDialog`, it was appear under the `WebviewScaffold`.

Below is my code,

```
child: Container(
  child: WebviewScaffold(
    url: agreementURL,
    withZoom: false,
    withLocalStorage: false,
    hidden: true,
    withJavascript: true,
  ),
),
```

When internet is not available I will show the `AlertDialog` but dialog appear under the `WebviewScaffold`.

Thanks.

Comment: The webview is not integrated in the widget tree, it is a native view on top of the flutter view. you won't be able to use snackbars, dialogs.

Comment: Ok thanks for comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hide method to hide the webview whenever you want to display the dialog.

Code:

```
final FlutterWebviewPlugin webviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin() ;
```

// when displaying the dialog

```
webviewPlugin. hide() ;
```